# Git: Repository not found, already cloned and clearly still exists?

Tags: git

Been using this repository for a while, today I wanted to pull down some changes I made locally on the production server and was greeted with repository not found? It clearly exists, I've pushed to it, but it apparently doesn't exist I can't get past it.

The repo is private but does exist.

Error:

```
root@status:/var/www/html# git pull
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: This isn't a Git issue, but rather a hosting site issue (GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, etc). They decide who you are based on your ssh key (or other authentication, but in your case, ssh key) and from there, they decide which repositories they'll admit exist to *you* (whoever they detected "you" to be). If you're authenticating as the wrong "you" you won't have the access you want.

Answer (score -2):

I had to add my first git account as a contributor to the 2nd accounts repository to get around the SSH key is already in use issue.